# sizeof on array function parameter will return size of 'int *' instead of 'int [] even if i use sizeof(array)\sizeof(array[0]);

Tags: c, arrays

I have a problem. I am getting an error:

```
 sizeof on array function parameter will return size of 'int *'
```

even after I use `sizeof(array)\sizeof(array[0])`. Could you help me please?

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{   int a=sizeof(values)\sizeof(values[0]);
    for(int i=0; i<a; i++)

        if(values[i]==value)
        return true;
        else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: What's with the **bold** text?

Comment: Please show the code examples that demonstrate the question.

Comment: Do not use an unnecessary formatting in the question text. But use a proper formatting for code and quotation. Also provide the code and the exact error message. Also make title clear and concise.

Comment: Because the function does not know the `sizeof` the array it was passed. It only knows the `sizeof` the pointer it was converted to.

Comment: So, sizeof(array)\sizeof(array[0]) is not a solution if I need to find out the length of the array?

Comment: `values` is not an array. It's a pointer.

Comment: You do know that `\\`` isn't a C operator, right?  The divide operator is the same as it is in almost any computer language, i.e. `/` just as you'd expect.  In any case, you have to explicitly pass in the size of the array.  Otherwise it doesn't have the information.

Comment: Yes, I posted it it with "\" by mistake. Sorry.

Comment: @Kateryna please follow the links. The original array definition is not withing the scope of the function it was passed to. The function knows *nothing* about it except its type. The function gets a pointer: that's all.

Comment: Thank you, now it becomes more clear!

Comment: Suggested reading: section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: Since arrays decay immediately into pointers, an array is never actually passed to a function. You can pretend that a function receives an array as a parameter, and illustrate it by declaring the corresponding parameter as an array:

 void f(char a[])
 { ... }
Interpreted literally, this declaration would have no use, so the compiler turns around and pretends that you'd written a pointer declaration, since that's what the function will in fact receive:
 void f(char *a)
 { ... }

Comment: Keith Thompson, thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: "arrays decay immediately into pointers," depends on the code.  Variable  `char b[5]; sizeof b` --> `5`, not the size of a pointer.  `b` is an array.  `void foo(char d[5]) { ... sizeof d` --> the size of a pointer. `d` is a pointer.